# Can i upload a video to my server with PhoneGap or another API?

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile, cordova

After having decided to use as PhoneGap API for the development of a small application, I tried to access the gallery of the phone to set up a system to upload files to my server.
Unfortunately, when I go to the gallery, the pictures are only available ...

Is there a way to access the video and send to the server, or another API who change HTML code in native app ? Or should I use a service for sending mail.
If yes, what is the name of this service?

Thanks to @ghostCoder

Just one correction, to be true :

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(successFn, errorFn, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: this.photoDestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source,
        mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA  });
```

**mediaType: this.fileMediaType.ALLMEDIA**

replace by

**mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes u can upload videos too.

use this

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(successFn, errorFn, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: this.photoDestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source,
        mediaType: this.fileMediaType.ALLMEDIA  });
```

this will open up gallery where u can choose a video too.

then u can upload it using

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="document";
    options.params={};
    options.fileName =  fileName;
    options.params.fileName = options.fileName ;
    options.chunkedMode = true;
ft.upload(fileURI, uploadUrl, successFn, errorFn, options);
```

Comment: Thank you ! I forgot to insert the mediatype... =)

Comment: @ghostCoder How can I add mimeType to filetransfer?

Comment: hello in your example FILE_URI & source not defined Error.